# android grid style view

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to produce a TV Guide style grid on Android and am not sure how to go about doing this.

It should be a list that contains channels that go down the left side of the screen.  Headers across the top should be broken out in to time slots in 1 hour increments.  The data should be program listings and should allow you to scroll from left to right to change time as well as up and down to change channels.

I was thinking that the original list would just be channels going down side.  Then override loading the rows so that it queries the channels in the selected time slot range.  I am not sure how to lock scrolling so all rows will scroll at the same time in the same direction.

Is something like this even possible? Is there a widget that is for loading large, grid-style data?

All data will be stored in a ContentProvider for easy querying.

I am just looking for where a good place to start would be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you looked at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html
is this not adequate for your needs?

Also, you need to keep in mind that a grid view of the kind you describe is patented by TVGuide, so, if this is a commercial product that you're making, you will need to license the rights to use such a grid, or be sued by them to stop using it.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I have not seen that view.  The application is open source, Mythtv Android frontend.

Comment: I see... well... just be aware of the patent... I have no idea if being open source protects you from having to license it, or if it's something that the end users (who utilize your code) will have to worry about.  Don't forget to give me the green checkmark if this view is really what you were looking for, and welcome to Stack!